# sql query condition java servlet

Tags: java, sql, servlets, conditional-statements

Hello i have sql query with condition like so:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM history WHERE identifikator IN (SELECT * FROM ban WHERE zabanovany = 0)");
```

it cannot find the column identifikator. 
it gives me error:  Unknown column 'identifikator' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

Comment: is identifikator a coulumn in history  table?

Comment: i have SQL db called ban where column identificator is located.

Comment: its no in history table, its in another table within same DB

Comment: If this is SQL you cant select * using an IN statement, you have to select only the field from the select that you want to match on, so you can only select the field identifikator from the ban table.  That may not be your error but once you fix your current error that will probably be a new error

Answer (score 2):

You need to select this column in your subquery

```
WHERE identifikator IN (SELECT identifikator  FROM ban WHERE.....
```

Comment: didnt work but this looks like best idea :) working on it

Answer (score 0):

You use the in operator to output a row by comparing it against a set of values. There is a short material that explains this very well here:
https://www.essentialsql.com/in-operator-with-a-subquery/
Think of it this way: the rows that you want to compare in your where clause are 2 dimensional. that is it has both rows and columns.

```
      WHERE identifikator IN (SELECT * FROM ban WHERE zabanovany = 0)")
```

IN operator is a linear operation and may not function properly when you are using all columns of a table for a where clause. So I think you may redesign your query to only select your column of interest. 
From your comment, you say idetificator is not in the history table so your problem may stem from there.